# Error during git pull in python fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I am using python fabric in my project mainly for deployment to the remote server. Inside the fabfile, i have written a function named deploy() for pulling the code to the github. When i execute the command "fab deploy", it results in an error like this:

**error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied**

Please help me in resolving this issue. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check permissions and ownership of .git directory and files in it

```
ls -al .git | grep FETCH_HEAD
```

There should be something like `-rw-r--r--` at the beginning of output.

If not fix it by setting them by:

```
sudo chmod -R 0755 .git
```

Comment: First of all many thanks for resolving this issue..After that i got another error like this:    **fatal: Unable to create '/var/www/epw/source/.git/ORIG_HEAD.lock': Permission denied**

Comment: That's still permission issues. Can you post output from `ls -al .git` ? Also if you have your git repository on remote machine try pulling clean copy from there.